# Select all checkbox acting on two different drop downs in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two menus in one form and a "select all" checkbox in each one. However, clicking one affect the two menus.

```
<div id="drop-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" name="select-all-cat" id="select-all-cat" /><label for="cities-label" class="categories-label">Select all</label><br>
```

And here is the second one :

```
<div class="test-label">
    <input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all"><label class="categories-label">Select all</label><br>
```

And the javascript :

```
 // Select all
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;
            });
    }
    else {
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    }); 


// Select all categories
$('#select-all-cat').click(function(event) {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;
            });
    }
    else {
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
```

How can I separate the two lists, which are in the same form?

Comment: Add complete `HTML` in the question

Comment: Your `$(':checkbox')` selects all checkboxes on the page.  Your selector needs to be more specific to make a distinction between the checkboxes in the two lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a context to the selectors matching each checkbox container. Assuming the group of checkboxes you want to act on are contained within the same div as each select all checkbox:

```
$('#select-all').click(function(event) {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(':checkbox', '.test-label').prop('checked', true);
...
$('#select-all-cat').click(function(event) {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(':checkbox', '#drop-wrapper').prop('checked', true);
...
```

Comment: What is `$(':checkbox', '#drop-wrapper')` selector

Comment: The second argument provides a context to search within; or in other words, it narrows your search for checkboxes to a containing element with id "drop-wrapper".

Comment: You could also write it as $('#drop-wrapper :checkbox') and $('#drop-wrapper').find(':checkbox')

Comment: I would also use input[type="checkbox"] instead of :checkbox for performance.

Comment: From the JQuery docs: "Because :checkbox is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :checkbox cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="checkbox"] instead." https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Add class filter to all your $(':checkbox')

```
 // Select all
    $('#select-all').click(function(event) {
        if(this.checked) {
            $('input:checkbox[class=select-all]').each(function() {
                this.checked = true;
                });
        }
        else {
            $('input:checkbox[class=select-all]').each(function() {
                this.checked = false;
                });
            }
        }); 


// Select all categories
$('#select-all-cat').click(function(event) {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('input:checkbox[class=select-all-cat]').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;
            });
    }
    else {
        $('input:checkbox[class=select-all-cat]').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is `$(':checkbox #select-all')`?